# Rango entre fechas y dias

Tags: php

Estoy realizando un modulo donde necesito sacar un rango de fecha especifico del 4 al 8 de un rango de fecha correspondientes es decir si ingreso una fecha de inicio del día 02 del mes  actual el va a ir  contando hasta llegar al día  4 y a partir de ese día  4 empezara a sumar 1 hasta llegar al día 8 que seria un total de 5 días de operación, todo bien hasta este punto, el único detalle es que necesito pasar otra fecha de ves en cuando, esa fecha tiene que calcular los días entre ese rango especifico de fechas y días, es decir si incluyo una fecha el día 05 del mes de abril  tengo que validar si se encuentra en al rango del 4 al 8 y de de ser así devolver los días correspondientes hasta la fecha final,  es decir  si la fecha intermedia es del día 07 de abril y la fecha de fin el 10 entonces tendría un rango desde el 07 al 10 contaríamos 3 días de operación

El problema aquí seria que la fecha de fin puede cambiar normalmente estoy sacando la fecha de fin  con la fecha del día  actual pero puede darse el caso que tenga una fecha de inicio de hace 20 días y entonces se tomaría fijo 5 días de operación ya sobre pasa los 8 días del rango especifico, así como también puede que tenga en ves de la fecha de fin llegar completo a los 8 días tener muchos menos días osea 7,6 o 5 días, cosa que no he encontrado una forma de realizarlo con una mejor lógica o mejor practica, aquí el código que llevo hasta el momento

Los días de operación sin una fecha intermedia se calcula bien ya que solo contamos con 2 fecha inicio y fin, el problema viene cuando incluimos una fecha intermedia y que se encuentre entre ese rango especifico y por supuesto que calcule desde la fecha de inicio intermedia - hasta la fecha de fin obteniendo los días de operación de esa fecha intermedia

Existe una mejor forma de realizar todo esto?

De antemano, gracias

```html
<?php

function getDaysVariation($dateStartVariationW,$dateStartIntermedie=NULL,$dateEndVariation){
    //inicio de la variación 

    $diff = $dateStartVariationW->diff($dateEndVariation);


    $daysOperation = 0;

    if($diff->days >= 4){

        if($diff->days >= 8){
            $daysOperation = 5;

            //le agrego 8 dias a la fecha de inicio de la variacion 
            $dateStartVariationEND = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2022-04-02'.'+ 8 days')));

            if(!is_null($dateStartIntermedie)){

                $diffIntermedie = $dateStartIntermedie->diff($dateStartVariationEND);

                $daysOperationIntermedie = 0;
                for ($i=4; $i <= $diffIntermedie->days ; $i++) {
                    $daysOperationIntermedie +=1;
                }

                $daysOperation = $daysOperationIntermedie;
            }
        }else{
            $days = !is_null($dateStartIntermedie) ? $dateStartIntermedie->diff($dateEndVariation) : $diff->days;

            for ($i=4; $i <= $days ; $i++) { 
                $daysOperation +=1; 
            }
        }    

    }


    return $daysOperation;
}


//Obtengo los días de  operación sin una fecha intermedia 
echo 'Sin fecha intermedia: '.getDaysVariation(new DateTime('2022-04-02'),NULL,new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2022-04-02'.'+ 9 days'))));

echo "<br/>";
//Obtengo los dias de  operacion con un fecha intermedia donde debo calcular que esa fecha se encuentre entre los días del 4 al 8
echo 'Con fecha intermedia: '.getDaysVariation(new DateTime('2022-04-02'),new DateTime('2022-04-05'),new DateTime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime('2022-04-02'.'+ 9 days'))));
?>
```

Comment: No entendí muy bien tu planteamiento, pero sospecho que esto es mucho más simple de hacer de como lo estás intentando ahora si usaras la clase `DateTime` y sus clases hermanas como `DateInterval` y `DatePeriod`. Ahora bien, planteas la pregunta de una forma muy confusa y no logro entender el *quid* del asunto.